# How to place k bishops on an nxn chessboard

Tags: chess, co.combinatorics

In how many different ways can **k** bishops be placed on an **nxn** chessboard such that no two bishops attack each other? Please try to respond with a formula and explanation.

Comment: A quick pointer in the right direction: you want "rook polynomials" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial), calculated separately for black squares and white squares, and then recombined somehow.

Also, this is not "combinatorial game theory" as that term is usually understood; I'll remove the tag.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Call this number $B_k(n)$. For fixed $k$ it is known that $B_k(n)$ has the form 
$P_k(n)+(-1)^nQ_k(n)$, where $P_k$ and $Q_k$ are polynomials. These polynomials have been computed for (at least) $k\leq 6$. We also have (unsurprisingly) the asymptotic formula
$B_k(n)\sim n^{2k}/k!$. 
For further information see http://www.math.binghamton.edu/zaslav/Tpapers/bishops.slides.20100729.pdf.

**Update.** I learned from Tom Zaslavsky that an explicit formula for $B_k(n)$ as a triple sum was given by C. E. Arshon in 1936.

Answer (score 9):

See my book
http://problem64.beda.cz/silo/kotesovec_non_attacking_chess_pieces_2013_6ed.pdf
, page 234-236. Number of ways to place k non-attacking bishops on an n x n board, (n>1)

[image]